# Is it appropriate to use a timestamp to distribute tokens?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, timestamp

To distribute tokens daily (per 24 hours ) among my participants in my dapp, i want to use block.timestamp . is that enough safe ? or should i using block.number for estimate 24 hours?
for example 24 * 60 * 60 / 17 sec (17 sec = block time for be mined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block timestamp can be manipulated slightly by miners, but in the long run not really. If the information is used for something like randomness, then typically the answer is "don't use it since it can be manipulated". But if it's for something like calculating farming rewards, it should be good enough - I doubt it matters too much if a miner modifies the timestamp by some seconds here or there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's conventionally better to use the block as the top guys have done. Also i believe you would require a way to trigger the operation as there's no such thing as schedule for Dapps except off-chain solution, in this case triggers the transaction every 24 hours.

Or better if you have transactions going on frequently, you can check if the block number where distribution happened is greater than `BLOCKS_PER_DAY` and run the distribution again. That's assuming that you've calculated your blocks per 24 hours.